# Ruby on Rails. Engine. Uninitialized constant error on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I have a rails 3 app that is working locally, I am using a rails engine for a module within my app. When I deploy to the production server I get 404 not found errors to my endpoints, more specifically this error:

`ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::V2::QuestionnaireController):`

However locally I don't get this error and I have access to this controller and all it's actions. My routes in the main app where I am making the calls is

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: "json"} do
 namespace :v2 do
  resources :questionnaires
```

Inside my Engine I have inside `models/qtn/questionnaire.rb`

`class Qtn::Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
 end`

and in my controller `controllers/questionnaire_controller.rb`

```
class QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questionnaires = Qtn::Questionnaire.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @questionnaires }
    end
  end
end
```

Could anyone help explain why this works perfectly on localhost but I can not access these endpoints once in production?

Answer (score 0):

I think your controller file controllers/questionnaire_controller.rb should have like below. Since routes says it is inside Api::V2

```
class Api::V2::QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questionnaires = Qtn::Questionnaire.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @questionnaires }
    end
  end
end
```